# Regular Expression to Extract String from URL

Tags: regex, r

I am looking to extract a string from a URL. Here is an example to illustrate what I am looking for.

Input URL: http://www.nba.com/bulls/stats/
Output   : bulls

In other words, I want to be able to extract the string between the second last and last "/" in the url. I know that I can split by "/" and extract the second last term, but am looking for a cleaner regex solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't grok regex and your string splitting option seemed pretty straight forward to me: `head(tail(unlist(strsplit(URL, "/")), 2), 1)`

Comment: The string between the second last and the last / is stats, not bulls.  Did you mean you want the string between the third last and second last /?

Comment: yes. i meant the one between the third last and second last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/?
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex can do the job

```
http[s]?://[\w\.]+/(\w+)/.*
```

Comment: I probably meant http[s]? instead of http[s]*

Comment: This won't match if there are any special characters in the string, such as `-` or `%`. I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

Comment: https? is simple as Czechnology mentioned above.. you don't need to put [] around s

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it by regex, you could simply do this (assuming JavaScript-style regex syntax):

```
/\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\/$/
```

For the sake of making it easier to understand, the .NET version would be this:

```
@"/([^/]*)/[^/]*/$"
```

However, I think the idea of splitting on `/` is really the right way to do this.